# uploading a video file to Facebook with description and action links

Tags: c#, facebook, video, upload

In C#, I'm uploading a video file to Facebook from a server, using the following method:

```
        string fullurl = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?" + "title=" + title + "&access_token=" + accessToken;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        byte[] returnBytes = client.UploadFile(fullurl, path);
```

path is the path to the video file on the server. This works, and shows a video uploaded post on the user profile. How can I add a text description (with link) and action links to that post?

please keep the answers in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should pass extra query string parameter - **description** - with embedded URL. Something like this:

```
var description = "Bring your conversations to life on Facebook. With face-to-face video calling, now you can watch your friends smile, wink and LOL.\n\nTo get started, visit http://www.facebook.com/videocalling"; 

string fullurl = string.Format("https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title={0}&description={1}&access_token={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(title), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(description ), accessToken);
```

Comment: Please Can You give me a Complete Code for posting video in facebook wall ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Following is my code:

```
string a = "User_Access_Token";
string fullurl = string.Format("https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title={0}&description={1}&access_token={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Dulha"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("hello"), a);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] returnBytes = client.UploadFile(fullurl, @"C:\Users\Users\Downloads\Dulha.mp4");
```